# haskell drop N'th element in list and replace other list with that index

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I have a problem, the question is;

Drop every N'th element from a list and replaces it with the elements in the list given in the second parameter.

Example;

dropandreplace “abcdefgh” 3 “hgfedcba”

output: “abhdeggh”

dropandreplace [1,0,3,0,5,0,7,0] 2 [2,4,6,8]

output: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

I did implement that code;

```
dropn :: [Char] -> Int -> [Char]
dropn list n = [ i | (i,c) <- ( zip list [1,2..]), (mod c n) /= 0 ]
```

But this code is drop N'th element from list.. How can i replace element of other list??

Comment: If the ratio between lengths of the list arguments is not correct given `n`, what should happen? (ex. `dropandreplace [dropandreplace [1,0,3,0,5,0,7,0] 2 [2,4,6]`)

Comment: What have you tried for the actual question? What isn't working? These are necessary parts for a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: give error message like "Second list hasn't got enough length" @mnoronha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using recursion and `splitAt`.

```
dropandreplace :: [a] -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
dropandreplace xs num (r:rs)
  = case splitAt (num-1) xs of
      (f, _:l) -> f ++ r : dropandreplace l num rs
      (f, _)   -> f -- `xs` if you want to preserve longer list
dropandreplace _ _ _ = []
```

Which is basically,

> take the first nth character, replace with target, and recurse.

---

Or another solution:

```
dropandreplace :: [a] -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
dropandreplace ss num rs = zipWith fromMaybe ss (expand rs)
  where
    expand [] = [] -- `repeat Nothing` if you want to preserve longer list
    expand (x:xs) = replicate (num-1) Nothing ++ Just x : expand xs
```

Comment: it works but if second list hasn't got enough length return missing list like;

dropandreplace [1,0,3,0,5,0,7,0] 2 [2,4,6]

output; [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: To address the uneven length direction (from comment above), we should add an error case for an empty second list: `dropandreplace _ _ [] = error "Replacement list has insufficient size"` before our base case.

Comment: @CanÇalışkan , I added two comments; if you want to preserve longer list use them.